# Django views that are inaccessible publicly but accessibly internally?

Tags: django, security

I have a few views I want to expose to apps internal to the server cluster. How can I do this securely?

The apps that want to access these restricted views are also using python, so if I can arguably bypass the HTTP tunneling and call directly to them, that's even better. I think these would be better suited as commands if that's the case, but how can another process invoke a Django environment's commands?

Answer (score 0):

Once you [load the project's settings](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) you can act as the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you basically want to extract some data from your Django site and use it elsewhere. Perhaps a couple of [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) that periodically output their data in some directory which you can then read from the other python apps? Depends on your data needs whether that's an option.

I'm doing this suggestion as those other apps seem to be on the same server (how could you otherwise run your site's python code from those apps?).